Can not access PostgreSQL Server on Windows from Linux on VMware Workstation
Windows host with Vmware Workstation, and a linux guest. I have another  Windows host with  PostgreSQL running on localhost:5432.
I established NAT connection to be able to use Internet in VM. Vmnet1 hostonly and vmnet8 NAT.
The problem occurs when I  import CSV data to my postgreSQL database using NIFI. It is unable to establish connection.
I also edited my server configuration so it listens to external requests. But still my attempts to connect to my server on main machine ended up like this:
psql -h 192.168.1.60 -p 5432 -U postgres -d POSTGRES

error: connection to server at "192.168.1.60", port 5432 failed: No route to host. Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

When I connect to online free psql testing server it connects successfully.
Also there are two hosts on the same net as my VM addresses 192.168.1.X, and it fails to connect to them.
Is there anything wrong?  Please free to ask questions.

localhost:5432 First of all, if you mean like it listens on 127.0.0.1 instead of e.g. 0.0.0.0, then it's not supposed to be accessible from any other hosts?

it is listening for 0.0.0.0 indeed, i edited the config of the posgresql

Consider adding the output of ip r of the VM. Also, are you sure it's not just the firewall on the servers?

default via 192.168.1.1 dev ens33 proto static 192.168.1.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.3
and yeah I checked firewall on both machines it is off

That looks like bridged networking instead of NAT or host-only? I assume the VM can reach the Internet? Is there any LAN host that is reachable from it? Is the bridge attached to a Ethernet NIC or WiFi adapter on the host?

It is NAT networking and Yes internet is reachable even some of the postgres servers outside my LAN, and would like to share some specification if that helps,
Vmnet1 host only - 192.168.33.0
Vmnet8 NAT 192.168.1.0 (and both have 255.255.255.0 netmasking just in case)

Why would you use the IP subnet that is used by your LAN for the NAT network?

ohh I did not think of it much , is it wrong?

it is essential that the host and the guest systems have different IP addresses and are reachable from each other. This could be virtual-lan or bridged networking.  NAT networking will not work.
It is furthermore essential that the postgresql is listening on a reachable ip address (you may need to reconfigure it)
From there it should be possible to get dignotics from the server and client that will be sufficient to resolve any further problems if you heed them carefully.

if you mind asking me why? Because when I read about NAT it is stated it uses Host's ip as it's own to access the internet, so why It can not connect to localhost of the main machine

that's the problem, the guest is pretending to be the host, so when the host tries to send to the guest it ends up sending to  itself instead.

Thanks Buddy I fixed as you said ans 'wuala' it is working now, have a nice day
